# Garbled Text using FETStationPanels, But Only the First time It's Called

Tags: apache-flex

I'm using the FETStationPanels from FlashEff2 with Flex 3. Unfortunately, it is garbling some of the letters.

Below is a simplified version of what the problem is:

Imagine that I've got three buttons. If any of the buttons are selected a titleWindow opens. Inside the titleWindow is some text pulled from a database that has the FETStationPanels effect applied to it, and an image. The first button that is clicked (it doesn't matter which one) will have garbled text. If I select another button, then the effect is fine and everything displays okay.

The FlashEff2 effect is fired on the creationComplete event of the TitleWindow.

I had a resize effect on the TitleWindow. I removed it, because I thought that that might be the problem. I put in a static height for the TitleWindow, but that didn't work either.

I also tried using callLater and setting a timer to delay the appearance of the image until well after the effect had ended, but that didn't work, either.

It's weird that the problem occurs only on the first button selected. After that it works fine.

I've been struggling with this problem for 3 days. I would post code, but there is too much for it to be useful. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem? Any general things that I can try or should check?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. When I add the TitleWindow, I put some effects on it in the main app and I forgot about them:

popWindow.setStyle("addedEffect", fadeInZoomEffect);
popWindow.setStyle("removedEffect",zoomFadeEffect);

When I took these out, my problem was solved. Everything works. I wish I had noticed those lines a few days ago!

Thank you.

-Laxmidi